# Double Slash in URL and double slash for comment

Tags: php, regex, bash, grep

I want to `grep` double-slash (Comment in PHP) but it seems conflict with double-slash in URL (http://)
How can I get only the second double-slash until the end of line from this url?

```
http://goo // gle.com
http://goo//gle.com
```

I've try with : `grep -P -o ".//.{0,}"`, but it give me output

```
http://goo // gle.com
http://goo//gle.com
```

And what I want is output like this :

```
// gle.com
//gle.com
```

So, how can I parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude the `:` character from the protocol:

```
grep -P -o "[^:]//.{0,}"
```

Executing:

```
grep -P -o "[^:]//.{0,}" <<< "http://goo // gle.co"
```

Outputs:

```
 // gle.co
```